# grep a text between lots of tags

Tags: bash, grep

Im tryng to get a text between a lots of tags, how can i get the text using grep?
Curl Return :

```
<member><name>blogName</name><value><string>Secret Labs - NTB4WORLD</string></value></member>
```

I Already try :

```
grep -Po '(?<=<member><name>blogName</name><value><string>)[^"]*'
```

but it return :

> `Secret Labs - NTB4WORLD</string></value></member>`

how if i need the result just

> Secret Labs - NTB4WORLD

Comment: `[^"]*` > `[^<]+`

Comment: use an XML parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test this on command prompt you can try this method if text are same as always, this method include sed and awk command first i set spaces and then i read and print the value with awk

```
echo "<member><name>blogName</name><value><string>Secret Labs - NTB4WORLD</string></value></member>" | sed 's/\(\b[<||>]\)/\1\ /g' | awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "<string>") {print $(I+1)" " $(I+2) " " $(I+3) " " $(I+4) };}' | sed s'/[<]$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//string)" your_file
```

Comment: Thank you for actually demonstrating a tool instead of simply referring to it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested use an XML parser, In case you still want to use `grep` give a try to:

```
grep -oP "<string>\K.+?(?=</string>)" file.xml
```

Or if you are in any `*BSD/macOS` try with `pcregrep`

```
pcregrep -o "<string>\K.+?(?=</string>)" file.xml
```

The `\K` can be read as excluding everything to the left before it and return only the right part `.+?(?=</string>)` until `</string>` is found.